# JQuery Mobile output to Google Maps info window using JSON

Tags: jquery, json, google-maps, jquery-mobile, infowindow

I am trying to implement a dynamic listview into a Google maps infowindow when the marker is clicked. I am using a piece of code that I know to be successful in another aspect of the application that I am developing.

I am displayed with a blank infowindow so I can only guess that I have made an error when assigning the output to the variable which becomes the content of the infowindow.

**The following JSON code is successful elsewhere in my application**

```
var file = "listview.php";
var output = '';

$.post(file, function(data) {

    $.each(data, function(index, value){ 
        output += '<li><a href="#"">' + value.site_name + '</a></li>';
    }); 
$('#liststores').html(output).listview().listview('refresh');
}, "json");
```

I have assigned the variables to be used in various functions. I have assigned the html variable some html code for the content of the infowindow. These are then bound to the function which runs the click funtion and sets the content of the infowindow.

```
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
        parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
        parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lon")));
    var html = '<div id="infowindow"><ul data-role="listview" id="liststores"></ul><div>';
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point,
        icon: icon.icon,
        id: id,
    });
    bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
}

function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    });
}
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. I believe that I have made the error in assigning the listview to the html variable as the JSON code is successful in assigning to another listview in the application.

Everything else in my code works, the markers are plotted onto the map but the marker click returns no data but no errors.

Answer (score 0):

It could be because the list view is not attached to the DOM, but only in a JavaScript variable

Have you tried doing something like this instead

```
 var html = '<div id="infowindow"><ul data-role="listview" id="liststores">'+output+'</ul><div>';
```